# Who are the daughters of Superman?

Tags: dc, superman, arrowverse, smallville, batwoman-2019

In *Batwoman* S01E09 aka "Crisis on Infinite Earths: Part Two", we see old Clark Kent (From Smallville) without powers talking to Lois about daughters. Who are these daughters? I only know about one daughter Lara. Is there any hint in any other DC property about those daughters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comic book miniseries *Superman: Secret Identity* (2004), a non-Kryptonian but slowly becoming Superman Clark Kent has two daughters, Carol and Jane Kent.  The girls in their late teens become as powerful as their father.  More here: https://superman.fandom.com/wiki/Superman:_Secret_Identity

A listing of many Elseworlds' Supermans and family: https://superman.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_as_a_father